# Jade mixin should return class to be appended to element

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm trying to append a specific class to an element depending on the outcome of a switch-statement. Code below is just for clarification.

```
mixin changeColor(color)
  case color
    when 1
       .blue
    when 2
       .green
    default
       .red

div.foo +changeColor(1)
    p Bar
```

Should result in

```
<div class="foo blue">
    <p>Bar</p>
</div>
```

The foo element may contain multiple child elements, not just the `p` tag.

Comment: I just solved this with javascript instead. Still interested in a mixin though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example without JS, "pure" *Jade*:

```
mixin changeColor(color)
  case color
    when 1
       div(class!=attributes.class).blue
         block
    when 2
       div(class!=attributes.class).green
         block
    default
       div(class!=attributes.class).red
         block

+changeColor(1)(class="foo")
  h1 More elements
  p.
    Bar
  .adiv
    p Bar
```

The output for `1`:

```
<div class="foo blue">
  <h1>More elements</h1>
  <p>Bar</p>
  <div class="adiv">
    <p>Bar</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks quite good. One thing though, is that the foo element may contain a whole bunch of other elements (not just the p-tag). This I forgot to mention in the q.

Comment: @estrar thats what I thought about. Now, with the blocks (see my update), it should work out with other elements below.

Comment: I'm filled with excitement. Gonna try it out this evening and report back to you. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try use js functions in Jade, like this

```
- var changeColor = function(color) {var returnedColor;switch (color) {case 0:returnedColor = 'blue';break;case 1:returnedColor = 'green';break;default :returnedColor = 'red';break;}return returnedColor;}

div.foo(class=changeColor(1))
  p Bar
```

Comment: Although js may be the best answer, I'd still like to have it done within a mixin.